# require 'debugger' => LoadError. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Context**

```
ruby 1.9.2p323 (2012-05-22 revision 35755) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]

rvm 1.16.6

gemsets for ruby-1.9.2-head 
   (default)
   global
=> rails321
```

---

**Trace**

```
$ gem install 'debugger'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed debugger-1.2.1

$ bundle show debugger
/Users/PH/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails321/gems/debugger-1.2.1

$ irb
> require 'debugger'
LoadError: no such file to load -- trace_nums
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails321/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.2/lib/tracelines19.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails321/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.2/lib/linecache19.rb:65:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails321/gems/debugger-1.2.1/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails321/gems/debugger-1.2.1/lib/ruby-debug.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails321/gems/debugger-1.2.1/lib/debugger.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/PH/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you bundle install? Any chance you'd post your Gemfile?

Comment: Here you're :-). Yes i did the bundle install...

Comment: It's a problem with linecache and your ruby version (not related to ImageMagick), switching to ruby-debug or ruby-debug19 should do the trick.

Comment: ruby-debug19 is no longer maintained, see README of the 'debugger' gem. It was the debugger that caused the problem. I posted an the result of : irb; require 'debugger'

Comment: how about require 'ruby-debug'?

Comment: It gives the same result... :/ but i'm using ruby 1.9.2 for a rails app. [The tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) gives this piece of advice : "if you are using Ruby 1.9, you can install a compatible version of debugger by running sudo gem install debugger"

Comment: Paste your "bundle show debugger" output

Comment: Seems you hit something here :-) ! I updated the post. Strange though...

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:

Try just "gem install debugger" instead of "sudo gem install debugger" since u r using rvm

Comment: Well, it's exactly what I did but see the result ? unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the bundler.

Create a Gemfile and put

```
  gem 'debugger'
```

in it.

Create a gemset

```
 rvm use 1.9.2
 rvm gemset create [my-app-name]
 rvm use [my-app-name] # 
 bundle
```

And re-test